# Trying to append lists consisting of several row on a data file in python

Tags: python

So this is perhaps a bit tough to describe

Lets say I have a csv fie with 1000 rows. and 5 columns. What I want to do is take
every value from column 5, and append it to a list. However, I want to separate all the values in that list by 5's. so something like

```
[[1,1,1,1,1][2,2,2,2,2][3,3,3,3,3][4,4,4,4,4]  . . . . .]
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include a small sample of the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this all at once, but unless speed is of the essence, I think it's a little cleaner to do it in two passes. First, read the required data into a flat list, then group that list into sublists five items long.

```
with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    # grab fifth column from each row
    data = [row[4] for row in reader] 

    # Split the flat data into sublists of length five
    split_data = [[data[i*j] for i in range(5)] for j in range(len(data)//5)]
```